# jHipster. Table filtering with pipe

Tags: angular, jhipster

I done pipe filtering on the client side as described in "Full Stack Development with jHipster".
It worked for string values, but not for numeric. Is it possible? 
And how to do filtering by range?

This code works:

***clients-rating.component.html***

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm1" type="search" [(ngModel)]="filter">

 <tr *ngFor="let clientsRating of (clientsRatings |  pureFilter:filter:'visitCount'); trackBy: trackId">              
                <td>{{clientsRating.visitCount}}</td>
 </tr>
```

***clients-rating.component.ts***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-clients-rating',
    templateUrl: './clients-rating.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./clients-rating.css']
})
export class ClientsRatingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    filter: String;

    constructor()
......
}
```

Comment: please provide code to help you better